# Rails LIKE - Query not working properly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a house model and business_model[] column. This column can be set as, "awake", "sleep" or "awake, sleep" with radio buttons, all string. I would like to get all the houses include business_model as "awake" for instance.

```
@house = (House.all).uniq.where("business_model like ?", "sleep")
```

I have tried that code. It works only if column is just "sleep". When it is "awake, sleep" it returns nil.

Why is that?

Comment: Just a note, your code is calling `where` on an array result set. You might want to brush up on the ActiveRecord interface. Something like `House.where('business_model LIKE ?', '%sleep%')` is what you're after.

Comment: @henners66 No, never refer to [w3fools](http://w3fools.com), refer to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) when using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to throw some wild cards in there.  Try `where("business_model like ?", "%sleep%")`.  Note that this will also catch things like `sleeping` and `asleep`.

You may want to consider using a JSON database column that gives you more control over the querying.

Comment: Why would he want to use a JSON column?

Comment: Too many things can go wrong with comma delimited strings. What if the database column ends up being "A, B", but the query comes in "B, A" (cause someday he'll want to query on multiple probably).  Mostly just feel that database are good at storing specific data so why try and DIY.

Comment: @coreyward Definitely, but didn't quite seem like what OP was asking about. Still worth some serious consideration.

Answer (score 3):

You're all jumbled up. `House.all` is going to return an Array, which means the `.where` is going to error because you're not calling it on an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You want:

```
House.where("business_model LIKE ?", "sleep").uniq
```

And yeah, you need a wildcard in there for the LIKE to be happy. If you don't need to find "sleep" within an attribute's value, you don't need to use LIKE.

```
House.where("business_model LIKE ?", "sleep%").uniq
```

The `.uniq` also jumps out at me a little, though. Does the `House` table contain duplicates? If so, that's probably not (i.e. "shouldn't be") necessary.